# how to re-position/float a search box onclick/onfocus

Tags: jquery, css, html

Please kindly assist me, I am trying to design a search box similar to the google home page in which it *(search box)* lays at the center but when on focus the text box floats to the top left. I have been able to alter the size of the search box but I cant seem to re-position it as desired.

```html
<style>

  input[type=text] {
    width: 450px;
  }
  
  input[type=text]:focus {
    width: 130px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border: 2px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('searchicon.png');
    background-position: 10px 10px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
    -webkit-transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }
</style>


<form id="form1" action="/search.php" method='GET' style="padding: 20px">

  <center>
    <h1>Huzzle</h1>
    <p>
      <input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="footer1" size='50' placeholder="  Search for service...."></p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </center>

  <body>
    <p class="footer1">
      <center>
        <input name='submit' type='submit' class="md-trigger md-setperspective    search" value='Search'>
      </center>
    </p>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show your existing (relevant) code.

Comment: please consider adding more descriptive information. Also, provide your current solution.

Comment: does the recent edit offer any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `position` attribute to modify the position of the input.

Additionally, you'll want to use `all` instead of `width` in your `transition` animation. Otherwise, it will not animate when it changes position.

Below is a simplified version of your code with only the relevant styles embedded.

```css
input[type=text] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

input[type=text]:focus {
  top: 10%;
  left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<input name="search" type="text" placeholder="Search for service....">
```

Of course, you'll want to edit the `top` and `left` settings to suit your exact requirements.